# YII + beforeSave() + getting max value from a table row

Tags: save, yii, max

i'm struggling to get my beforesave in Yii Framework working this way:

when the user sends the form, beforesave() should fetch the highest number in a column called 'order' and insert a value of order+1 into current 'order' field.

After a few hours spent here reading posts i managed to compile this thing:

```
 public function beforeSave()

 {

   if (parent::beforeSave())
   {

        if($this->isNewRecord)
        {

             $criteria->select='max(order) as myMaxOrder';

             $get_it= new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this), 
             array('criteria'=>$criteria,));

             $got_it=$get_it->getData();

             $whatweneed=$got_it[0]['myMaxOrder'];

             $this->order=(int)$whatweneed+1;

        }

        return true;
    }
    else
    return false;
 }
```

The code gets the MAX from 'order' but i really did't know how to deal properly with the  YII's getData() method, so i var_dumped it and saw that what i was looking was there but i still don't know how to access this value apart from doing

```
 $whatweneed=$got_it[0]['myMaxOrder'];
```

Could you tell me how to do it right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you set up your database so that the Order `id` is the Primary Key (it should already be anyway), just set it to "[Auto Increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)". If Auto Increment is set on your Primary Key (`id`), then when you `save()` a Model in Yii without an `id` it will automatically save it with an `id` one higher than the max. You won't need to do anything in `beforeSave()` at all! It is free functionality.

But perhaps I am totally misunderstanding your question. Maybe this is not an auto-incrementing primary key column for some reason. In that case, something like this should work (assuming your model is Order and you column is also, for some reason, called "order"):

```
$maxOrderNumber = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
  ->select('max(order) as max')
  ->from('order')
  ->queryScalar();
$this->order = $maxOrderNumber + 1;
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Thaddeusmt! Many thanks for you explanation, the second part of your answer was what i was trying to achieve. It was supposed to be a part of a 'ordering' mechanism with jQuery.sortable UI which would allow the user to drag'n'drop the <li> elements in specific order. Now works like charm :) THanks again!

Comment: Hmm that makes sense, storing a sort order. Glad I could help out!